# update email selected from another table using the foreign key relation

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, subquery

I have 3 tables called *Contact*, *APP_User*, *Customer Table*. here I want to select email from my Contact table based on Contact_ID as Foreign key in App_User table and I want to Update the selected email into my Customer table based on App_User_Id  as Foreign key in Customer table and primary key in APP_User Table.

Clearly:- I want to fetch email where `Contact.contact_ID = APP_User.Contact_ID` and Update the fetched email to `Customer.emial` where A`PP_User.App_User_Id = Customer.App_User_Id`

```
UPDATE CRM.CRM_CUSTOMER_USER 
  SET EMAIL = (SELECT EMAIL 
               FROM QA29.ST_CONTACT 
                 INNER JOIN QA29.ST_APP_USER ON QA29.ST_CONTACT.CONTACT_ID = 129) 
WHERE APP_USER_ID = 120;
```

But it results in:

> ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Comment: Have you written any code?

Comment: Yes, I wrote this query but it is error ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

     UPDATE CRM.CRM_CUSTOMER_USER SET EMAIL = (SELECT EMAIL FROM QA29.ST_CONTACT INNER JOIN QA29.ST_APP_USER ON QA29.ST_CONTACT.CONTACT_ID = 129) WHERE APP_USER_ID = 120;

Comment: Your sub-query has no proper join condition between the two tables

Comment: or you need no join in the subquery at all if `QA29.ST_CONTACT.CONTACT_ID` is PK.

Answer (score 0):

Join condition is missing in the inner query.

There must be multiple rows returned by the following query which is the cause of the issue:

```
SELECT
    EMAIL
FROM
    QA29.ST_CONTACT
    INNER JOIN QA29.ST_APP_USER ON QA29.ST_CONTACT.CONTACT_ID = 129;
```

You must restrict this to single record using valid join condition, something like the following:

```
UPDATE CRM.CRM_CUSTOMER_USER
SET
    EMAIL = (
        SELECT
            EMAIL
        FROM
            QA29.ST_CONTACT
            INNER JOIN QA29.ST_APP_USER 
            ON QA29.ST_CONTACT.APP_USER_ID = QA29.ST_APP_USER.APP_USER_ID -- OR SOMETHING LIKE THIS
            AND QA29.ST_CONTACT.CONTACT_ID = 129
    )
WHERE
    APP_USER_ID = 120;
```

Cheers!!